# Modify an InputStream and convert it to Outputstream

Tags: java, xml, inputstream, outputstream

Im developing a program where i receive an XML file as InputStream. I have to make some changes and then return it as OutputStream.

Here is my code:

```
public void execute (InputStream xmlEntrada, OutputStream xmlSalida) {

    SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
    Document document;

    String idDocCobro, idCobro;
    String sociedad, ejercicio, numDocCobro;

    try {

        document = saxBuilder.build(xmlEntrada);

        Element raiz = document.getRootElement();

        List piDocCobros = raiz.getChildren("Pagos");

        for (int i = 0; i < piDocCobros.size(); i++) {

               Element nodePiDocCobros = (Element) piDocCobros.get(i);

               sociedad = nodePiDocCobros.getChildText("Sociedad");
               ejercicio = nodePiDocCobros.getChildText("Ejercicio");
               numDocCobro = nodePiDocCobros.getChildText("NumDocumentoCobro");

               idDocCobro = sociedad + ejercicio + numDocCobro + System.currentTimeMillis();

               nodePiDocCobros.getChild("iddoccobro").setText(idDocCobro);

               List piCobros = nodePiDocCobros.getChildren("Pago");

               for (int y = 0; y < piCobros.size(); y++) {

                   Element nodePiCobros = (Element) piCobros.get(y);

                   nodePiCobros.getChild("iddoccobro").setText(idDocCobro);

                   idCobro = numDocCobro + System.currentTimeMillis();

                   nodePiCobros.getChild("idcobro").setText(idCobro);

                   List piDocumentosRel = nodePiCobros.getChild("DocumentosRelacionados").getChildren("DocumentoRelacionado");

                   for (int z = 0; z < piDocumentosRel.size(); z++) {

                       Element nodePiDocumentosRel = (Element) piDocumentosRel.get(z);

                       nodePiDocumentosRel.getChild("idcobro").setText(idCobro);

                   }

               }
        }  

        copy(xmlEntrada, xmlSalida);

    } catch (JDOMException | IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}   

public static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (true) {
      int bytesRead = in.read(buffer);
      if (bytesRead == -1){
        break;
      }  
      out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```

My problem is when i try to read the XML in the function `copy` because the stream is already closed, so i get an Exception. The stream closes itself when i use the `saxBuilder.build` sentence at the beginning of the program. I can't save the text before in a `byte[]` variable because i will modify it during the program.

Any idea?

Thank you so much in advance! :)

Comment: You are reading the stream into a document. What you should be doing is not copy the stream - you should be writing the document into the output stream.

Comment: You already have the document as a `Document`. You don't need to read the input stream again. You can process the 'Document`. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some of you told me, i was making a silly mistake. What i had to do is to pass the documento to OutputStream. I did that with the next piece of code:

```
XMLOutputter xmlcode = new XMLOutputter();
xmlcode.output(document, xmlSalida);
```

Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The InputStream you've read is not the object that contains the modification you made. Your modifications are inside the Document object.

That's what you need to send to the OutputStream.